# PHP Class Scope confusing with call_user_func()

Tags: php, class, scope

```
class A
{
    public static function who1()
    {
        var_dump(get_called_class());
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    public static function who2()
    {
        parent::who1();
    }
}
call_user_func(array('B', 'parent::who1'));
B::who2();
```

What I expect:

```
string 'B' (length=1)

string 'B' (length=1)
```

Actual returns:

```
boolean false

string 'B' (length=1)
```

Can anyone tell me why the output is different from what I expected?

see also:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

**edit:**
Maybe my old code is not clear, here is the new example:

```
class A
{
    public static function who()
    {
        var_dump(get_called_class());
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    public static function who()
    {
        echo 'hehe';
    }
}
call_user_func(array('B', 'parent::who'));
```

why it output false?

Comment: You don't need to add the `parent` part in the call to `parent::who1`. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php: `For example, when you extend a class, the subclass inherits all of the public and protected methods from the parent class. Unless a class overrides those methods, they will retain their original functionality.`

Comment: Don't use `parent::`: `call_user_func(array('B', 'who1'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PHP manual documentation for Object Inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php):

> For example, when you extend a class, the subclass inherits all of the public and protected methods from the parent class. Unless a class overrides those methods, they will retain their original functionality.

As stated above, there is no need of `parent` prefix there in [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call-user-func):

```
call_user_func(array('B', 'who'));
```

---

You got `FALSE` in [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) because [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call-user-func) stated method call outside a class. So [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/get-called-class) behaved as expected (or mentioned in the manual):

> Returns FALSE if called from outside a class.

Comment: I don't get it. get_called_class() is still inside method who(), who() is inside class A. If I call it like this A::who(); it will output A.

Comment: @nut `get_called_class()` probably in this case can not properly determine caller class. And this seems like a bug to me. Looks like `call_user_func(array('B', 'parent::who'));` forces `::who()` to be called outside a class scope.

Comment: Yea, my example seems complex, I will post it on bug list to get the detailed information. And thanks for mention Object Inheritance